How to delete multipath (disk) device?
This is on TrueNAS 13.0U6.3 (FreeBSD 13.1-RELEASE-p9)
I had a disk in my ZFS pool die. I replaced it, but I updated TrueNAS (Core) first - I think I was on U6.0 or U6.1 before the update.
When I try to replace the dead disk in my pool with the fresh one, what comes up to replace the dead disk with is multipath/disk1.
$ gmultipath list shows this:
Type: AUTOMATIC
Mode: Active/Passive
UUID: 472fbec0-b03b-11ef-9225-eb3c2b011256
State: OPTIMAL
Providers:
1. Name: multipath/disk1
   Mediasize: 2000398933504 (1.8T)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 4096
   Stripeoffset: 0
   Mode: r0w0e0
   State: OPTIMAL
Consumers:
1. Name: da3
   Mediasize: 2000398934016 (1.8T)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 4096
   Stripeoffset: 0
   Mode: r1w1e1
   State: ACTIVE
2. Name: da7
   Mediasize: 2000398934016 (1.8T)
   Sectorsize: 512
   Stripesize: 4096
   Stripeoffset: 0
   Mode: r1w1e1
   State: PASSIVE

I know I didn't explicitly create a multipath disk. I've done a bit of research on it and I don't think it was enabled before - so I'd like to disable/delete it if it's possible to do so safely. From what I can tell, the multipath device disk1 just contains da3 and da7, neither of which are in my zpool right now (but either of which I'd like to use to replace the now-dead disk).
$ sudo gmultipath remove da3 multipath/disk1 just results in gmultipath: Device da3 not found. I've tried da7 in place of da3, and disk1 in place of multipath/disk1, with the same result. Both da3 and da7 show up in /dev. What am I doing wrong?
$ gmultipath status
          Name   Status  Components
multipath/disk1  OPTIMAL  da3 (ACTIVE)
                          da7 (PASSIVE)

$ glabel status
                                      Name  Status  Components
gptid/ba57595c-ee74-11ec-b51b-399e00f59ed1     N/A  da1p2
gptid/d0b76aad-bfbd-11ec-996d-4d60e9b1c6c6     N/A  da0p1
gptid/ba4d8354-ee74-11ec-b51b-399e00f59ed1     N/A  da6p2
gptid/ba1ee75b-ee74-11ec-b51b-399e00f59ed1     N/A  da4p2
gptid/ba11edb8-ee74-11ec-b51b-399e00f59ed1     N/A  da2p2
gptid/8968c667-48aa-11ef-b8e7-f5ee91c5a64b     N/A  da5p2
gptid/ba05228b-ee74-11ec-b51b-399e00f59ed1     N/A  da8p2
gptid/b9bc5150-ee74-11ec-b51b-399e00f59ed1     N/A  da9p2
gptid/b9cf5ec0-ee74-11ec-b51b-399e00f59ed1     N/A  da1p1


gmultipath destroy disk1 did the trick.
